# Acceder a los elementos de un Dialog Fragment llamado desde un fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment, spinner, diálogo

El caso es que mi MainActivity es una BottomBarNavigation Activity, que posee tres fragments donde se cargan todos los elementos para que el usuario interactue. En uno de esos fragments hay una lista en la cual, cuando el usuario selecciona un elemento, la aplicación debe mostrar un DialogFragment personalizado donde el usuario debe introducir algún otro dato.

El problema es, que cuando trabajo con ese DialogFragment e intento acceder a los componentes con findViewByID algo falla porque se quedan a null. El código que uso para acceder a los componentes es el mismo que uso en los demás fragments y no me había dado fallos hasta ahora.

Este es mi método onCreateView. a pesar de asignar al spinner el componente, cuando entra el método cargaSpinner() en el cual se le asocia un adapter obtengo un nullPointer en el spinner

```
public class DialogSeleccion extends DialogFragment{

  Spinner spinner;
  View view;

  public DialogSeleccion(){}

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstances) {
      view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_seleccion_layout, container);

      spinner= (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinnerPrueba);
      cargaSpinner();
      return view;
  } 
}
```

Comment: como obtienes inflater para pasárselo al constructor? Prueba a obtenerlo en esa misma función con LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

Comment: Puedes asegurarnos que el layout `dialog_seleccion_layout` si tiene un un Spinner con el id `spinnerPrueba`?

Comment: Me acabo de dar cuenta que el spinner que estaba seleccionando no era el de ese layout. Tenia dos spinner con nombres similares y cogí el que no era. Gracias!